# dxgettext and Windows 10

Tags: delphi, gettext

Has anyone got [dxgettext](http://dxgettext.po.dk/) running under Windows 10?

I [installed dxgettext](http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/gettext/0.14.4/gettext-0.14.4-bin.zip) from the [offical homepage](http://dxgettext.po.dk/) under Windows 10, which worked fine.

But whenever I try to run some of the installed tools (e.g. `msgfmt.exe`), they don't really run, but call themselves again, generating thousands of processes and making the system crawl.

This is what happens:

- I call `msgfmt --help`
- the executable `msgfmt` hangs, blocking the command window
- in the TaskManager I see houndreds of `msgfmt.exe` processes popping up

I think, I have to replace the gettext tools of the dxgettext package with some newer version but before trying to figure it out I first wanted to ask if someone else experienced similar problems and found a working solution.

My questions:

Has anyone got the tools coming with dxgettext running under Windows 10?

What steps have been necessary to get it to run?

Comment: We haven't had any problems using it in Windows 10.

Comment: Try running them as Administrator, so you can discard permission's problems to your project files.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Tried running as Admin - same problem. Btw, there are no project files involved. Even `msgfmt` or `msgfmt --help` hangs. I found this problem while trying to figure out, why jvcl installation hangs.

Comment: @JoshKelley OK. Maybe a problem with my machine. But I am not the only one [experiencing *this* problem](https://translate.google.de/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.delphipraxis.net/188630-ist-das-ein-fehler-dxgettext-2.html) under Win10.

Comment: The installer on the official home page is pretty old. Last time I looked it contained several outdated dlls and executables from the original gnugettext project that did not work correctly under recent Windows versions. You could take those from my buildtools repository on source forge. These work for me. No guarantee that they work for you though. https://sourceforge.net/p/dzlib/code/HEAD/tree/buildtools/trunk/

Comment: @dummzeuch Thank you for your info. Meanwhile I already had [replaced the executables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40173753/2523663), but from a different source. This resolved the problems. I assume your link would have worked too. Thx

Comment: @dummzeuch If you make your comment an answer I'll accept. This helped a lot!

Comment: @AloisHeimer done

Comment: Why the downvotes? Anything unclear? I'm not a native speaker, so please feel free to correct me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer on the official home page is pretty old. Last time I looked it contained several outdated dlls and executables from the original gnugettext project that did not work correctly under recent Windows versions. You could take those from my buildtools repository on OSDN. These work for me. No guarantee that they work for you though.

https://osdn.net/projects/dzlib-tools/scm/svn/tree/head/buildtools/trunk/

Comment: I tink to replace the outdated executables is the right answer. I added an [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40173753/2523663) to describe the steps I actually did to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the problem in the following way:

1. I downloaded https://github.com/mlocati/gettext-iconv-windows/releases/download/v0.19.8.1-v1.14/gettext0.19.8.1-iconv1.14-static-32.zip from https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html
2. I replaced the following files from the installation directory of dxgettext with files from the zip archive:

   ```
   msgattrib.exe
   msgcat.exe
   msgcmp.exe
   msgcomm.exe
   msgconv.exe
   msgen.exe
   msgexec.exe
   msgfilter.exe
   msgfmt.exe
   msggrep.exe
   msginit.exe
   msgmerge.exe
   msgunfmt.exe
   msguniq.exe
   xgettext.exe
   ```

**Result:**

- Dxgettext and the tools, I use, seem to work fine. I found no problems with my workflow so far, with one exception:
- If I use `assemble` to embed `mo`-files into an exe compiled with `JvGnugettext.pas`, I get the following error:

  > Pach code “6637DB2E-62E1-4A60-AC19-C23867046A89” was not found in .exe file. Are you sure the .exe file has been compiled with the correct libraries?

  This may not be related to the original problem. However, it is resolved by replacing the original `assemble.exe` with the version from https://sourceforge.net/p/dzlib/code/HEAD/tree/buildtools/trunk/ (see [answer by @dummzeuch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173753/2523663)).

Comment: It would also be possible to get the sources of dxgettext and compile the assemble.exe yourself.

Answer (score 5):

I've been having these issues too with dxgettext 1.22, in Windows 10 1607. I changed some DLLs at first but kept having the bash.exe looping and hogging my PC to death.

So what I did was basically install latest Cygwin 32bit and replaced the appropiate DLLs. I kept the ones for gettext. Instructions:

1. Download and fresh install dxgettext-1.2.2.exe from http://dxgettext.po.dk/download as admin. Restart.
2. Download Cygwin 32bit from https://cygwin.com/install.html  in a different folder from dxgettext (I took the default, c:\cygwin)
3. Run setup-x86.exe and select  "Base" Package (Install).  Next, Select Required packages just in case.
4. Move the following files from dxgettext folder to a backup folder (we'll use some DLL later):

   ```
   cyg*.dll 
   bash.exe
   ```
5. Copy from c:\cygwin to the dxgettext folder the following files:

   ```
   bash.exe  (set to run as admin)
   cygwin1.dll
   cygiconv-2.dll
   cygintl-8.dll
   cygreadline7.dll
   cyggcc_s-1.dll
   cygncursesw-10.dll
   ```
6. Recover the file(s) below from the backup folder (See #4) and copy to the dxgettext folder.

   ```
   cyggettextsrc-0-14-1.dll
   cyggettextlib-0-14-1.dll
   cygintl-3.dll
   ```
7. Running like this, you might get error 740 (requires elevation). So:   Set ggmerge.exe,ggfmt.exe to run as admin

** EDIT** Found online this very interesting link, from a programmer who offers a free backup written in Delphi. The good thing is he adapted the dxgettext tools to run in Windows 10. This helped me a lot. 
http://personal-backup.rathlev-home.de/translate.html