# RAD Studio 10.2.3 Jedi JVCL Install Problem

Tags: delphi, installation, jedi, rad-studio

I've uninstalled my RAD Studio 10.2.2 and installed 10.2.3 in my Win10 development VM.  Along the way I uninstalled all the previous 3rd-party libs, including the Jedi GetIt packages, and per the instructions got rid of all the old Jedi source and DCP/DCLs.  I'm attempting to install them back into 10.2.3 via GetIt.  The JCL libs install fine, but when I try to install JVCL, the installation batch file hangs after compiling the installer and the VM comes to its knees.  I rebooted, started taskmgr and watched as the batch file ran - it appears to go into a loop creating many instances of msgfmt.  I've tried removing it all again, downloading and installing the 3.8 version myself and running the install batch file by itself, same problem; then backing up to the 3.6 version that had installed OK in 10.2.2, and it does the same thing.  If I edit the batch file to skip the language-setup section, the batch file completes OK, but trying to re-run the GetIt update causes it to re-download and replace that batch file. :(

The installer does compile before the languages part of the batch file is reached, so I tried running the installer directly.  I assume I'm not passing it cmd line info it needs, because it compiles the 64-bit libs fine but chokes immediately on compiling the 32-bit version of JvCore250.bpl with an unspecified compile error.

Anyone else run into this? Is a solution known?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to ultimately be a pathing problem.  When multiple installations of the IDE exist on a machine (e.g. my VM has or previously had D2007, XE2 and 10.1 on it), the PATH environment variable can be too long - edit the PATH in the system to remove the old/stale paths.  Then make sure that the library paths in the IDE includes `$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\release` or you'll get "can't find RTL" when building the packages.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is generated from the msgfmt.exe of dxgettext.
msgfmt.exe generates multilanguage messages, for a multilanguage support of jvcl installation.

For the specific problem of msgfmt.exe try to see this: [dxgettext and Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162954/dxgettext-and-windows-10)

I resolved the problem opened the install.bat file in jvcl folder, and I commented (with ::) every line where the msgfmt is executed.

Attention:
If you use getit I suppose you have to open the folder where jvcl is downloaded and search install.bat (I didn't use getit)

Instead I downloaded jvcl directly from github in my component folder, and I did what is written above in that folder.